# Scheduling tasks in Java/Spring

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

There is a requirement in the project that will have a scheduled task that will do some job.

The project is Spring based and the scheduled job will be part of the application war.I have 
never implemented this kind of functionality before.

I have heard of Quartz. Also, I read somewhere that Spring provides some functionality to schedule tasks. So, I was thinking if I am already using Spring then why to go for some other API(Quartz).

I am not sure which one to use? what will be the pros/cons of one over another?

Please suggest what will be the best way to approach my requirement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have used Spring's Task execution and scheduling - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html

Comment: Check out http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-namespace-scheduled-tasks

Comment: The above link doesn't tell which one is better? Spring scheduler or Quartz.Please help

Comment: If app needs task execution with-in single JVM and your is not deployed in clustor, you spring's thread pool executor. If app needs to be deployed on clustor use Spring abstraction over Quartz with persistence to external db option.